# @Query return wierd error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

im creating store locator using google map. im using springboot-starter-jpa

and put the harsvine formula to my repository service like below :

```
//this is store locator in km
@Query("SELECT p, (6371 * acos(cos( radians( :latitude ) ) * cos( radians( p.latitude ) ) * cos(radians( p.long ) - radians( :longitude )) +sin(radians(:latitude)) * sin(radians(p.latitude)))) AS distance FROM Location p HAVING distance < :radius ORDER BY distance LIMIT 25")
List<Location> getMeListPlaces(@Param("radius") long radius, @Param("latitude") long latitude, @Param("longitude") long longitude);
```

and the error that ive got is like below

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: HAVING near line 1, column 233 [SELECT p, (6371 * acos(cos( radians( :latitude ) ) * cos( radians( p.latitude ) ) * cos(radians( p.long ) - radians( :longitude )) +sin(radians(:latitude)) * sin(radians(p.latitude)))) AS distance FROM com.mashitah.model.Location p HAVING distance < :radius ORDER BY distance LIMIT 25]
```

am i doing some mistakes here? because i taking this formula for google map documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/clothing-store-locator)

Comment: The google documentation is about a MySQL SQL query. What you have there is a JPQL query. Those are two different languages. Just like C++ and Java are two different languages.

Comment: @JBNizet, by all means, i have mysql jdbc to translate jpql to mysql query. still on the same mysql platform using sql syntax. so, im here not addressing the platform i used, but why the syntax query over there is not accepting by mysql.

Comment: It doesn't even go to MySQL. It's not accepted by the Hibernate JPQL/HQL parser, because you send it a SQL query, not a JPQL/HQL query.